# How to let the variable be stored in a machine register using C#?

Tags: c#

I had referenced at MSDN and found the `register` keyword, but it's only in C++.

Syntax:

```
register int x = 0;
```

Can you tell me how to do that with C#?

Comment: Why are you trying to do register level operations in C#? Thats assembly work!

Comment: May I ask, Why do you want that with C#? What is the motivation behind it.. AFAIK, C# doesn't have any direct way of specifying it..

Comment: `register` in C++ doesn't even do what you think it does, and it is deprecated.

Comment: if you wanna deal with registers you shouldn't be using a high-level language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do that in C#. C# is compiled to MSIL, which is then compiled to native code by the JIT.

It's the JIT that will decide whether a variable will go into a register or not. You shouldn't worry about this.

As MSIL is meant to be run on different architectures, it wouldn't make much sense to include such a feature in the language. Different architectures have a different number of registers, which may be of different sizes. That's why it's the JIT's job to optimize this.

Answer (score 2):

> By using a keyword? `No`.

With unmanaged code, you certainly can though... I mean, you really don't want to... but you can : )

It is useful in extreme optimizations, where you know for sure that you can do better than the `JIT Compiler`.  However, in those circumstances, you should probably be looking at straight unmanaged `C` anyway.  So, I strongly urge you to do that if you can.

Let's assume you can't, and this absolutely positively must be done from `C#`

`C#` is compiled to MSIL, which takes those choices out of your hands.  It actually does quite well too, so well in fact that there's rarely a need to optimize by hand.  But, with `C#` being a managed language you have to step into an unmanaged section to do it.

There are several methods, both with and without reflection - and both using inline and external.

Firstly, you might compile that small fast section in `C`, `ASM` or some other unmanaged language as a DLL and call it unmanaged from `C#` in much the same way you'd call `WinAPI` functions... pay attention to calling conventions, there are several and each places a slightly different burden on `caller`/`callee`... for example, in terms of how parameters are passed and who clears up the stack afterwards.

Alternatively, you could use `fasmNET` or similar to include inline assembly for any routines which must be ultra-fast.  fast can compile strings of Assembler in c# (at runtime) into a blob of memory which can then be called unmanaged from c#... many examples exist online.

Alternatively, you could externally compile just the instructions you need, provide them as a byte array yourself, and call the byte array as code in the same manner as above, but without a runtime compilation step.

There are also many tricks you can do with inline IL that can help you fine-tune your code without the JIT compilers involvement, these may or may not be useful to you depending on your project.  Custom IL sections can be accomplished both with inline IL and dynamic IL and can give you considerably more control over how your c# application runs.

Depending on how often you need to switch back and forth between managed and unmanaged, you can also create a separate application domain from your code, and load your unmanaged code into that... this can help you separate the managed/unmanaged concerns and thus avoid any costly switching back and forth.

But...

I will not give code, as to how you do it depends greatly upon what you're trying to accomplish.  This is not the type of thing where you should just paste a code snippet into your project - you need to research the various methods, learn about their overheads and drawbacks, and then implement them with care, wisdom and due diligence.

Personally, I'd suggest learning C and offloading such computationally important tasks as an external service.  This has the added advantage of allowing you to use processor affinity to best effect.  It also allows you to write clean, normal, sensible `C#` for your head end.

But trust me, if your code is too slow and you think using registers for a few variables will speed things up... well... 95% of the time, it absolutely won't.  `C#` does a tonne of work behind the scenes to wrangle those CPU resources as effectively as possible ... if you step in and snatch control of a few registers from it, it will usually end up producing less optimal code overall.

So, if pressed to guess at your best strategy, I'd suggest offloading that small task to a seperate C program or service, and then use C# to throw it problems and gather output.  Coupled with affinity, this can result in substantial speed gains.  If you need to, it is also possible to set up shared memory between managed and unmanaged code - although this requires a lot of forward planning, may require experience using a good commercial debugger, and certainly isn't for the beginner.

Note that whichever way you go, portability WILL be adversely affected.

Re-evaluate whether you really need to do this at all.  There are likely many more sensible and productive optimisations that can be done from within C#, in terms of the algorithm itself, which you should explore fully before going anywhere near the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
There aren't any real useful registers in IL and there is no guarantee that the target machine will have registers. The JIT or Ahead-of-time compiler will make those decisions for you.